# Do several modify operations at once

Tags: oracle, xquery, xquery-sql

In the code bellow, first there is a element that needs to be add, them in the rest of the code one attribute named t is created or updated.

```
declare
  LOG_REFERENCE xmltype:=xmltype('<log  />');
begin

  select  XMLQuery('
    copy $p := $p1 modify insert node <update data="{$p2}" />
              as last into $p/log
    return $p
    ' PASSING LOG_REFERENCE AS "p1", to_char(systimestamp) AS "p2" RETURNING CONTENT)
      INTO LOG_REFERENCE from dual;

  select  XMLQuery('
    copy $i := $p1 modify(
      if (fn:exists($i/log[1]/@t)) then (
        replace value of node $i/log[1]/@t with $p2
      ) else (
        insert node attribute  t {$p2} into $i/log[1]
      )
    )
    return $i
    ' PASSING LOG_REFERENCE AS "p1", to_char(systimestamp) AS "p2" RETURNING CONTENT)
      INTO LOG_REFERENCE from dual;

  dbms_output.PUT_LINE(LOG_REFERENCE.getClobVal());
end;
```

My problem is that i wanted to join the two modify into one xquery call like this

```
declare
  LOG_REFERENCE xmltype:=xmltype('<log  />');
begin

  select  XMLQuery('
    copy $p := $p1 modify(
     insert node <update data="{$p2}" />
              as last into $p/log
    )

    copy $i := $p modify(
      if (fn:exists($i/log[1]/@t)) then (
        replace value of node $i/log[1]/@t with $p2
      ) else (
        insert node attribute  t {$p2} into $i/log[1]
      )
    )

    return $i
    ' PASSING LOG_REFERENCE AS "p1", to_char(systimestamp) AS "p2" RETURNING CONTENT)
      INTO LOG_REFERENCE from dual;

  dbms_output.PUT_LINE(LOG_REFERENCE.getClobVal());
end;
```

In my head this is correct, But obviously im missing something. Or it can't be done in oracle xquery?

the error message that was given:

> ORA-19114: XPST0003 - Error during parsing the XQuery expression: 
>   LPX-00801: XQuery syntax error at 'copy' 7       copy $i := $p modify(
>   -       ^ ORA-06512: em line 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both operations in a single modify clause:

```
declare
  LOG_REFERENCE xmltype:=xmltype('<log  />');
begin

  select  XMLQuery('
    copy $p := $p1 modify(
     insert node <update data="{$p2}" />
              as last into $p/log,
      if (fn:exists($p/log[1]/@t)) then (
        replace value of node $p/log[1]/@t with $p2
      ) else (
        insert node attribute  t {$p2} into $p/log[1]
      )
    )

    return $p
    ' PASSING LOG_REFERENCE AS "p1", to_char(systimestamp) AS "p2" RETURNING CONTENT)
      INTO LOG_REFERENCE from dual;

  dbms_output.PUT_LINE(LOG_REFERENCE.getClobVal());
end;
/

<log t="19-JUN-17 21.25.56.434586 +01:00"><update data="19-JUN-17 21.25.56.434586 +01:00"/></log>

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Which seems to get the same result as your original block, with or without an existing `t` attribute.

Incidentally, you're currently relying on your NLS session settings to format the timestamp as a string; it would be better to do it explicitly, e.g.

```
...
    ' PASSING LOG_REFERENCE AS "p1",
        to_char(systimestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF6') AS "p2"
      RETURNING CONTENT)
      INTO LOG_REFERENCE from dual;
```

to get an output like

```
<log t="2017-06-19T21:28:54.896506"><update data="2017-06-19T21:28:54.896506"/></log>
```